# How do I access the hash represented by this dumper output?

Tags: perl

I am hacking a git-svn Perl script. I have a `$paths` variable which I think contains an array of individual paths, but I am having a hard time iterating over it. My end goal is to to add an additional attribute to one path.

Here is the dumper output.

```
{
    "/dira" => {
        action        => "A",
        copyfrom_path => undef,
        copyfrom_rev  => -1
    },
    "/dira/dirb" => {
        action        => "A",
        copyfrom_path => undef,
        copyfrom_rev  => -1
    },
    "/dira/dirb/test.55mb.file" => {
        action        => "A",
        copyfrom_path => undef,
        copyfrom_rev  => -1
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that output, `$paths` is a reference to a hash of references to hashes.

If you know which path you want to extend, you don't need to iterate:

```
$paths->{'/foo/bar'}{'my_attribute'} = 42;
```

If you want to do this uniformly to all paths, you can do this:

```
for my $attrs (values %$paths) {
    $attrs->{'my_attribute'} = 42;
}
```

See [`perldoc perldata`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldata) for information about hashes and [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreftut) for references and nested data structures.

Comment: Using the `values` instead of the `keys` if you don't need the keys is an idiom that somehow never got stuck in my head. I have to remember it.

Comment: @simbabque It's neat because you can use it to modify the values themselves: `for my $v (values %h) { $v++; }`. `values` returns a list of aliases and `for` aliases the loop variable to the current item, so `$v` directly refers each hash value.

Comment: Yes, that's very useful. And it saves an arrow, if you use them, which I do. :-)

Comment: @simbabque Not only it saves an arrow, it also saves the hash lookup for `$v = $h{$k}`.